# 'WE are the most precious person in the world' or 'WE are the most precious persons in the world'

Tags: meaning, grammar

maybe it is simple qusetion. 
I just make that 
like 'you're precious in the world'

person? persons? people?

but, i confused. . pls help me

Comment: "We" is plural and so needs to match with "people" (not "persons" unless you want to sound very stilted).

Comment: Both sentences sound odd to this native speaker but "We are the most precious person in the world" is ungrammatical unless the person speaking is an hereditary head of state (like the Queen of the UK or the King of Sweden). No one else should use "we" when talking about themselves and no one else. "We are the most precious people in the world" is grammatically correct (although _very_ arrogant, pompous, self-satisfied and likely to cause offence) but "We are the most precious person in the world" only makes sense in the case of an arrogant, pompous, self-satisfied and offensive king or queen.

Comment: How many people does *we* refer to? There is something called *the royal we*, used by kings and queens (and occasionally others) where *we* denotes one person. But if *we* refers to more than one person, it should be *people*.